Efficiency fluctuation in a setup combining buck converter, filter capacitor, inductor etc. What might be the reason?
The input current increases suddenly  after 1.5A, higher than the output side while using a setup with a buck converter. This results in a very steep decrease of efficiency, 85% to almost 10%. The same thing happens from the very beginning if I remove the input capacitor. The schematic of the circuit is given here.

The inductor I used is a gapped EE ferrite. I used two E cores like the picture below to make the inductor with 24 turns around the core.


I used two polarized box capacitors, 1.1mF each. I also used a TLP250 IGBT driver in this setup. I suspect the reason to be saturation of tge inductor.
How can I measure the saturation current of the specific inductor that I used in this setup?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to supply a lot more design and test data

Please provide a full schematic.

There seems to be some aliasing in the schematic that makes values and symbols poorly or unreadable. Could you take a better screenshot? || What are the phototransistors? Part number, pinout and wiring. What are the part numbers of everything else? (Label the schematic if possible; designators are required.) || What is the "X" component? What is the 15V battery, is it in fact a battery?

Metagross Metang - In addition to other requests for info: (a) Did you use the actual ferrite cores in the image you copied? Or just something like that? (b) In any case, to comply with the site referencing rule, please link to the source of the copied image. (c) The schematic shows a FET as the switching device, but the text says it's an IGBT. Which is it? (d) Do you have an oscilloscope to view signals at relevant nodes? (e) What troubleshooting have you done already? (f) Please add photos of the actual hardware. (g) Is this intended to be a 60 V battery charger? TY

@SamGibson a) yes b) https://fair-rite.com/product/e-cores-9498103002/ c) igbt 60n100 d) yes f) The inductor photo is here. You can see the two capacitors on the back. g) yes but not industrial purposes, I wanted to design a 1kW charger to learn more about them and gain experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated

@SamGibson e) Before 1.5A, the input current maintains an almost 1/5 ratio with the output current.Then the input current rises much higher than the output, like, input current was measured to be 4.4A when the output current was 2A.This was unexpected and tried increasing the output current more The input current first decreases and then gets clamped at 4-5A range while the output slowly increases. For 4A at input, found 9.6A output.Used VARIAC here instead of direct supply.And if I remove the input capacitor, the input current abruptly rises from the beginning,no current ratio is maintained.

There seems to be some miscommunication here -- what is 1.5A, where? I see no point indicated on the diagram, nor what instrument and method was used to measure this figure. Was this the input current? What was the input voltage under the same condition? Output voltage and current? What if anything was the load? There are still many things missing here; I'm afraid there isn't much we can do with what has been given. Perhaps another perspective will be helpful: describe your project as if you want someone else to duplicate it exactly. What details are missing from that?

@TimWilliams Sorry,by output current 1.5A,I meant the current after the output capacitor or the load current.Measured it using multimeter on DC setting, that can measure upto 20A.Similarly,used multimeter in series after the input capacitor to measure input current.The converter is a buck,for 20% duty cycle, input voltage of the buck(across input cap) stays almost 5-6 times the output voltage(across load).The load is a 5ohm ceramic resistor, and the input voltage was around 45V when I measured 1.5A after the output capacitor.The input current was 0.3A.The exact efficiency measured then was 85%

@TimWilliams  I have used a variac connected to supply and a rectifier module after that.And then increased this output current by changing variac and raising output voltage of the buck, then the input current behaves abnormally as I mentioned.Another note,when I used lamp as load, I got upto 200V at the input of buck and still got 81% efficiency(20% D). The output current was 0.8A this time. So, I suspect my problem has nothing to do with voltage, and the output or load current is the main issue. Increasing it seems to disturb the circuit and that is why I suspect my inductor to be saturated.
